# Apache Access Logs: Can we configure what NOT to log?

Tags: apache, logging, access-log

My Apache (Linux/CentOS) is behind a load balancer (AWS ELB). So in my Apache `access_log`, there are tons of useless logs, like:

- `- - - [13/Jan/2016:23:38:02 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/1.0"`
- `- - - [13/Jan/2016:23:42:39 +0800] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache (internal dummy connection)"`

These two logs heavily flooded in my `access_log`. Actually these two are totally useless for me (since they are just internal health checkers only), but affecting/confusing to my log analyzers, like `awstats`. So i kinda don't want to have this kind of log entries.

- Is there a way to configure Apache to WHAT NOT TO log?